# How to create a 1000 color RGB rainbow gradient in python

Tags: python, colors

I need to create a 1000 color RGB gradient (from red, to yellow, to green, to blue, to purple), and it needs to output all the values in a long list. Currently I've only gotten the red to blue part finished. The code I've tried works, but surely there's a more efficient way of doing this right?

```
huehue1 = 255
huehue2 = 0
huehue3 = 0
greenhuetoggle = False
for i in range(0, 1001):
    print('[' + str(huehue1) + ', ' + str(huehue2) + ', ' + str(huehue3) + ', ' + '255]')
    if huehue1 > 0:
        huehue1 -= 1
    if huehue2 < 256 and greenhuetoggle == False:    
        huehue2 += 1
    if huehue2 == 256:
        greenhuetoggle = True
    if greenhuetoggle == True:
        huehue2 -= 1
        huehue3 += 1
```

Here's the output. https://pastebin.com/0pniBL2u Is there any way to do this better? I feel like it's very slow to create a long list of toggles and variables.

Comment: Why do you not just use `print([huehue1, huehue2, huehue3, 255])`? Apart from this, and changing `and greenhuetoggle == False` to `and not greenhuetoggle` and `if greenhuetoggle == True` to `if greenhuetoggle`, I don't see much that can obviously be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to look at the output, assuming that's what you want is:

- red starts at 255 and goes to 0 and then stay at 0
- green starts at 0, goes up to 255 and then back to 0
- blue starts at 0 and once red hits 0, it starts going up to 255

One issue I can see with the output vs. your description is that you say it needs to happen in 1000 steps, but of course you end up with only 512 - perhaps you meant to say 'at most'?

A simpler implementation of what you already have:

```
for r, g, b in zip(
    (list(reversed(range(256))) + [0] * 256),
    (list(range(256)) + list(reversed(range(256)))),
    ([0] * 256 + list(range(256)))):
    print([r, g, b, 255])
```

Or, slightly nicer, with an import of a standard lib:

```
from itertools import chain

for r, g, b in zip(
    chain(reversed(range(256)), [0] * 256),
    chain(range(256), reversed(range(256))),
    chain([0] * 256, range(256))):
    print([r, g, b, 255])
```

If you need more control over how each line looks instead:

```
    print(f'[{r},{g},{b},255]')
```

Comment: Why not just `print([r, g, b, 255])`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 certainly nothing wrong with that - I mistakenly thought there were no spaces in the example output, but there actually are, so I agree.